# Use useEffect to load a script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am using a sdk and according to the documentation I have to load the script:

```js
 <body>
 <script>
    my sdk code
    my sdk code
    my sdk code
  </script>
  ..
  ..
  </body>
```

How you can see inside  tag I have the sdk code. I am using reactJs  and I want to load this script in `useEffect`  hook. 
Question: How to run the script of sdk not in body tag but in **useEffect** hook?

Comment: Could be in a couple of ways. Care to share the docs so we can help you figure it out?

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart#loading

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier,  could you help? I want to implement share dialog

Comment: I might. But have you tried just writing the code inside a `useEffect` hook? Because you know what you need to do so it's unclear where you are stuck.

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier,  i tried but the code doar not run ok, one time it is running and another no. I do not why this is happening. Could try on your side?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could share your code in which you actually try to build it.

Answer (score 12):

You'll need to add the script tag dynamically inside of a React component. The best way to do this is to use the Context API. It will provide a single point which loads the scripts and initiates the FB SDK and can let every children know when the scripts are loaded and the SDK is ready to use.

> **FbSdkScript.js**

```
import React, { 
  createContext, 
  useContext, 
  useState, 
  useEffect 
} from 'react'

// Context.
export const FbSdkScriptContext = createContext()

// Create a custom hook to use the context.
export const useFbSdkScriptContext = () => useContext(FbSdkScriptContext)

// Provider of context.
const FbSdkScriptProvider = ({
  appId,
  autoLogAppEvents = true,
  xfbml = true,
  version = 'v8.0',
  children 
}) => {
  const [hasLoaded, setHasLoaded] = useState(false)
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false)

  /**
   * Extra security measure to check if the script has
   * already been included in the DOM
   */
  const scriptAlreadyExists = () => 
    document.querySelector('script#fb-sdk') !== null

  /**
   * Append the script to the document.
   * Whenever the script has been loaded it will
   * set the isLoaded state to true.
   */
  const appendSdkScript = () => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.id = 'fb-sdk'
    script.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'
    script.async = true
    script.defer = true
    script.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
    script.onload = () => setHasLoaded(true)
    document.body.append(script)
  };
  
  /**
   * Runs first time when component is mounted
   * and adds the script to the document.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!scriptAlreadyExists()) {
      appendSdkScript()
    }
  }, []);

  /**
   * Whenever the script has loaded initialize the
   * FB SDK with the init method. This will then set
   * the isReady state to true and passes that
   * through the context to the consumers.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasLoaded === true) {
      FB.init({
        appId,
        autoLogAppEvents,
        xfbml,
        version 
      })
      setIsReady(true)
    }
  }, [hasLoaded])

  return (
    <FbSdkScriptContext.Provider value={{ isReady, hasLoaded }}>
      {children}
    </FbSdkScriptContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default FbSdkScriptProvider
```

The share component itself now has nothing to worry about. It only needs to know when the script is loaded and the FB SDK has been initialized. It will get that signal through the `isReady` state from the Context API.

> **FbShareDialog.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useFbSdkScriptContext } from './FbSdkScript'

/**
 * This is the button that will trigger the dialog.
 * It uses the context created in the previous snippet to
 * know when the script has loaded and the API is ready
 * to use. 
 */
const FbShareDialog = ({ method = 'share', href }) => {
  const { isReady } = useFbSdkScriptContext()

  /**
   * Open share dialog when the button is clicked.
   * This will only be available when the isReady
   * state is true.
   */
  const handleClick = () => {
    FB.ui({
      method,
      href,
    }, response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  }

  /**
   * If FB SDK is not yet ready, don't render the button.
   */
  if (!isReady) {
    return null
  }

  /**
   * Otherwise do render the button and set an onClick
   * event listener which triggers the dialog.
   */
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Share me</button>
  )
}

export default FbShareDialog
```

And it all comes together in a single component where the context provider is a parent of the share dialog button. You only have to pass your `appId` to get the  `FbSdkScriptProvider` component working. And add the `href` to the button to tell the `FB.ui` what href to refer to.

> **App.js**

```
import React from 'react'

import FbSdkScriptProvider from './FbSdkScript'
import FbShareDialog from './FbShareDialog'

const App = () => (
  <FbSdkScriptProvider appId={'your-app-id'}>
    <FbShareDialog href={'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'} />
  <FbSdkScriptProvider/>
)
```